# loop through different colours in forloop and save them, in RStudio

Tags: r

Suppose I am running a forloop that runs 15 times, each time the forloop uses the plot() function with a different colour

```
colours<- c()
for(i in 1:15){
  
  plot( ... , col = i)
  colours[i] <- i
  
}
```

Is it possible to some how replace the numbers with the actual names of the colours so when I refer pack to the plots, I can see what iteration of the loop gave that colour. Without replacement, the vector `colours` will just end up looking like

`[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15`

Comment: Not all colors have nice "names". The colors used by base R can be retrieved/set with `palette()`. You'll see that most of those colors are just hex codes. You'd have to come up with your own name for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the colors in `colours`, the loop will work.  Use either R's named colors (some [listed here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Etzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf)) or with a hex code (`#ff0000`).

```
colours<- c('#58f86e','blue','green','yellow','black', 'hotpink1', 'magenta2')
for(i in 1:length(colours)){
  
  plot( mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt , col = colours[i], main = colours[i])
  
  
}
```

[image]

[image]